# Number formatting with substr

Tags: perl

Can anyone explain the logic behind what is happening in this code? I know what its purpose is, but not exactly how it works.

```
for ( my $i = -3; $i > -1 * length($x); $i -= 4 )
{
substr( $x, $i, 0 ) = ',';
print $x;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print the value of `$i` to see what's going on:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $x = 1234567890;

for (my $i = -3; $i > -1 * length $x; $i -= 4) {
    substr( $x, $i, 0 ) = ',';
    print "($i)<$x>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
(-3)<1234567,890>
(-7)<1234,567,890>
(-11)<1,234,567,890>
```

Negative position in `substr` means "count from the right". Specifying length 0 means we're *inserting* a substring. We're adding commas before each group of 3 digits from the right, but we need to change the position by -4 because we need to jump over the comma added in the previous step.

Comment: That makes sense. What about the part where -1 is being multiplied by the length?

Comment: Note that `substr( $x, $i, 0 ) = ','` is the same as `substr( $x, $i, 0, ',' )`